# Signalr Reconnects every 2 seconds even thought server is up

Tags: javascript, signalr

So we have a signalr application that when the server has a hickup, the clients call "reconnect" every 2 seconds indefinitely (even though the server is back up). When the page refreshes it connects just fine. couples things that I noticed:

1. The reconnect request in the Network dev tools shows "Status Code: 101 Switching Protocols"
2. We're using ms-signalr-client for the wrapper around the javascript client, it runs "reconnect", then immediately is successful, then immediately closes the connection

This is causing our prod server to go down 3 or 4 times a day as soon as the clients lose connection for a second

Comment: What transports and authentication are you using?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Figured out the issue. there was an exception being thrown SILENTLY in the Reconnected Stack. not sure why considering the same code is called in the Connect Stack. anyway, reworked it that we don't have to make the same call, and not need it. works fine now